# Convert specific attribute value in a JSON object to IEnumerable in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a JSON object that looks like this

```
{
"totalCount": 2,
    "students": [{
        "name": "abc",
        "data": {
            "Maths": 20,
            "Science": 25
        },
        "score": 10.0
    },
    {
        "name": "xyz",
        "data": {
            "Maths": 44,
            "Science": 12
        },
        "score": 11.0
    }]
}
```

I want to deserialize this JSON object to an `IEnumerable<String>` that contains all the names.

I want - 
`private IEnumerable<String> GetAllNames(string json)` to return `["abc","xyz"]`

**This is just sample data (and not homework!!).** Any advice on how to achieve this would be appreciated. I'm using Newtonsoft library but haven't been able to do this effectively yet. I do not want to iterate through the objects and construct the list myself, any direct way of doing this?

**EDIT** - 
This is what I'm doing currently

```
var studentList = new List<string>();

var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);

foreach (var data in json.students)
   {
     catalogsList.Add(data.name.toString());
   }

return catalogsList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetAllNames(string json)
{
    JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
    return jo["students"].Select(s => s["name"].ToString());
}
```